# JAVA Properties file in Windows Virtual Store causing problems through updates

Tags: java, javafx, inno-setup

I'm developing a self-contained java applets, which runs with a *.properties file, for config parameters. The app is installed with an Inno-Setup installer, and something weird happens to the properties file :

1. First execution :
   The app doesn't write anything to the Windows Virtual Store, even though the config parameters are retained.
2. Second Execution : The app directly copies the properties file to the Windows Virtual Store, at X:\Users\USRNAME\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\APPNAME\app
3. On uninstall : Every component of the app disappears from the computer, except from that properties file in the Virtual Store.
4. On update : if the structure of the config.properties file has changed through an update, e.g. for the needs of the app, the current config.properties in the Windows Virtual Store is not updated, and this occasionally causes bugs.

Does anybody know how to prevent windows from storing this file in the Virtual Store ? If not, how to manage it throughout updates ? For now, we can't deploy the soft because of this exact problem of updates.